# Make package available in Vue with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I used the vue-cli to create a Vue project with typescript.
Now my App.vue looks omething like this:

```
...
Component({
    components: {NavigationDrawer, AppBar}
})
export default class App extends Vue {...}
```

I want to add the [v-hotkey](https://github.com/Dafrok/v-hotkey/blob/master/README.md) package to my app. The instructions say to use this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueHotkey from 'v-hotkey'

Vue.use(VueHotkey)
```

But when I do that

```
<template>
    <div v-hotkey="keymap"></div>
</template>

...
import VueHotkey from 'v-hotkey';

Vue.use(VueHotkey);

@Component({
    components: {NavigationDrawer, AppBar}
})
export default class App extends Vue {
    ...
    get keymap() {
        return {
            // 'esc+ctrl' is OK.
            'ctrl+space': this.toggleSearch()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: hotkey

(found in <App> at src/App.vue)
```

I think I am including the package in a wrong way. But vue with typescript seems new and I couldn't find anything to help me. I also looked [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a file `v-hotkey.d.ts` with the following lines:

```ts
declare module 'v-hotkey' {
    import { PluginObject } from "vue";

    // options: alias map
    const VueHotkey: PluginObject<Map<string, number>>;
    export default VueHotkey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Local import:**

Inside a component we normally don't use Vue.use();
if you want to use v-hotkey inside a particular component then we import it in that component only, after that we can use it there. (locally import)

```
<template>
<div vue-hotkey ="keymap"></div>
</template>

...
import VueHotkey from 'v-hotkey';
```

**Global import:**

if you want to use it in every where in the application we have to import it in a place like main.ts or create a separate file with the necessary code and pass it as a vue instance constructor parameter(like router) and use it as global. To make it available for anywhere in the application can use "Vue.use();"

```
import VueHotkey from 'v-hotkey'

Vue.use(VueHotkey)
```